# How to reload rails environment? Is `reload!` command depracated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reload

I tried to reload rails environment with the `reload!` command, I think it might be depracated. Does anyone know the modern way of reloading the rails environment? This book is available free for download, Im on page 79, it's Michael Hartl's "RailsSpace: Building a social networking website with ruby on rails", published in 2007, several people suggested that I give up on the book already, I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a modern way of doing things before I gave up on the book. So many experts on stackoverflow helped me get through the book already, I decided to take my chances.

Here is a link to the book: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ca98/3b5098cd5957dc1842bb4bf3175406624bca.pdf?_ga=2.121598472.1814901715.1569094472-1963651489.1569094472, its one of the only FREE sources out there for building a social media website thats why I cant give up on it so easily, even though it was published in 2007 and its a bit outdated. Plus I just want to see what stackoverflow can do for me before I just give up on the book. So many experts on stackoverflow helped me make it this far, Im curious to find out if I can get through the entire book with stackoverflow. If anyone knows a better source that's free, please send me a link. Right now page 79, is the roadblock, its that `reload!` command that might be depracated. Maybe its an expert on stackoverflow that knows the knew command for it. If that's you please help. I already tried googling it, it took me straight here to stackoverflow lol. I decided to post a question of my own, that other guy's question doesn't seem to match mine so here I am. Please help if you can.

Comment: Why do you think the `reload!` in the Rails console is deprecated? Works perfectly fine in me example Rails 6.0 app. Do you get an error message or unexpected behavior? Please explain.

Comment: You continue to ask questions about issues you're running into using a book about Rails **1**. This book is **12 years out of date**. I again **strongly** recommend that you stop using this book, abandon everything you have done so far, and start using a new book, tutorial, or other resource for a modern version of Rails. There is no one that can help figure out problems with Rails 1 because no one uses Rails 1.

Comment: Rails has come a long way since 2007 when that book was published. Rails 6.0 just launched and added significant new features like ActionCable (websocket support), and full Webpack integration. It's worth noting that the [Rails Documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org) is actually pretty good. The only drawback is it doesn't have concrete examples like that particular book does.

Comment: If you're a fan of the book because of Michael Hartl, and not just because it was available for free, I'd echo the other suggestions - you absolutely need a newer resource.  Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) would be a much better starting point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the Rails console (`rails c`, or more formally `bundle exec bin/rails c`) you should be able to run:

```
reload!
```

That reloads the active environment, specifically anything within `app/` and `config/routes.rb`, but other things *will not* be reloaded until you exit and restart the console. This has always been the case.

Note that this is **only within the Ruby interactive environment**, as in you'll have a prompt that looks like this:

```
irb(main):001:0>
```

If you see something else you may not be in the Rails console and are trying to run the command in the wrong context. A common mistake is trying to run this in he shell itself where you'll get an error like:

```
-bash: reload!: command not found
```

One other thing you may need to do if you're having trouble getting things to load that should be there is to stop the Spring launcher, forcing it to reload:

```
 spring stop
```

That kicks the [Spring application preloader](https://github.com/rails/spring) which can sometimes get confused about what's going on and needs a reset.